# How can I insert the Python timestamp time.strftime into a pathname for the filename output?

Tags: python

Goal is to put a date-timestamp as the filename for output of photos of a Python script.

```
timestr=time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

gives me exactly what I want for print (timestr) but I cannot figure out how to insert this string for the file name into what I am given by:

```
camera.capture('/path/to/save/file.jpg')
```

Comment: You can concatenate your two strings like: ```path += timestr + ".jpg"```, where ```path =  "/path/to/save/"```.

Comment: This concatenate answer solved my problem; each photo taken now has a unique filename.

Comment: timestr=time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

Comment: timestr=time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")                       camera.capture ('/path/to save/' + timestr + ".jpg")                                  gives me the unique file name I needed for each photo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are halfway done, now just try to change the file name that you are saving

```
dir_path='path/to/save/'
timestr=time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
file_name=timestr + '.jpg'     #file name
path=dir_path+file_name        #abs path of file
camera.capture(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proper solution:

```
import time
import os

timestr, file_path = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"), '/path/to/save/file.jpg'
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
output = "{0}_{1}{2}".format(filename, timestr, file_extension)
print timestr, filename, output
```

output variable will have the desired result